# How can i allow a background page to access the page i'm visiting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to have the background page in my extension access the page i'm visiting, but because the background page is loaded into background.html it can't access the current page and it isn't able to find things on the page i'm visiting.

I want some JavaScript code to be executed on the current page when i click a context-menu item. Something happening when i click it works fine and all but i can't manage to access things on the page I'm visiting.

How do i do this?

Comment: You can likely achieve your desired behavior with [`tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript), along with [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) from the injected script back to the background page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to interact with the web page and [message-passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) for communication between the background page and content script.